# How can I find the maximum value and its index in array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, max, matrix-indexing

Suppose I have an array, `a = [2 5 4 7]`. What is the function returning the maximum value and its index?

For example, in my case that function should return 7 as the maximum value and 4 as the index.

Comment: Write `max` at the command line and press F1 for help (if on a Windows system, other systems will use another key) and read the documentation.

Comment: There are many tutorials out there to get you the basic Matlab functions familiar :) [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/student_center/tutorials/mltutorial_launchpad.html)

Comment: [Matlab's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/index.html) (also the available launching `doc` in the command window) contains almost anything you will ever need to know about matlab functions, examples and tutorials.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The function is `max`. To obtain the first maximum value you should do

```
[val, idx] = max(a);
```

`val` is the maximum value and `idx` is its index.

Comment: whats with the semi colon?

Comment: @technazi MATLAB normally announces every variable assignment in stdout for some godforsaken reason. The semicolon suppresses that.

Answer (score 16):

For a matrix you can use this:

```
[M,I] = max(A(:))
```

I is the index of A(:) containing the largest element.

Now, use the ind2sub function to extract the row and column indices of A corresponding to the largest element.

```
[I_row, I_col] = ind2sub(size(A),I)
```

source: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html

Answer (score 10):

In case of a 2D array (matrix), you can use:

```
[val, idx] = max(A, [], 2);
```

The idx part will contain the column number of containing the max element of each row.

Answer (score 5):

You can use max() to get the max value. The max function can also return the index of the maximum value in the vector. To get this, assign the result of the call to max to a two element vector instead of just a single variable.

e.g.
z is your array,

```
>> [x, y] = max(z)

x =

7

y =

4
```

Here, 7 is the largest number at the 4th position(index).

Answer (score 5):

**3D case**

Modifying Mohsen's answer for 3D array:

```
[M,I] = max (A(:));
[ind1, ind2, ind3] = ind2sub(size(A),I)
```

Comment: This is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This will return the maximum value in a matrix

```
max(M1(:))
```

This will return the row and the column of that value

```
[x,y]=ind2sub(size(M1),max(M1(:)))
```

For minimum just swap the word max with min and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
max_a = max(a)
a.index(max_a)
```